# no se envia el formulario con NODEJS

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

app.js

```
//CONNECT TO DATABASE
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb+srv://obsJ:prueba12@cluster0-eoq97.mongodb.net/Register?retryWrites=true&w=majority",{ useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true } ,function  (err,db){
    if(err){
        console.log("Unable to connect DB. Error: " + err)
    }
    else{
        console.log('Connected to DB');
    }
    db.close()
});


app.post('/Register',function(req,res){
    const data = new User({
        EmailR: req.body,
        PasswordR: req.body
    })
    data.save((err,doc) => {
        if (err){
            res.send('NOT SUCESSFUL')
            console.log(data);// vista del resultado de data
        }else{
            if (doc){
                res.send('Successful!')
            }
        }
    });
})
```

no llega a enviarse el registro, cuando el botón submit es presionado se queda cargando al final el navegador me tira **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**  pero el console.log captura que los input no estan vacios, por si las dudas las credenciales estan correctas.

Comment: Una pregunta en el log te muestra que logra de manera efectiva  conectarse a la bd?

Comment: Correcto el Log sale Connect to DB

Comment: Quita esa línea: `db.close()` y comenta los resultados.

Comment: **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** esto es el resultado que me tiro el navegador no se si esta parte como tengo el action tenga algo que ver ``action="http://127.0.0.1:27017/Register"`` lo puse asi porque la route no me agarra si lo pongo /Register

Comment: @MauricioContreras  Ya solucione el problema, pero ahora mi duda es que no entiendo porque no funciono de la manera que lo había hecho,  el problema fue que el userSchema lo tenia en user.js , entonces lo que hice fue escribirlo en el app.js , **aunque mi pregunta** es que a pesar de que hice un **REQUIRE** al user.js no funciono de la misma manera que pasar  el código de user.js para el archivo **app.js**